# Can I drill a bathroom vent through what appears to be an exterior joist?

Tags: vent, joists, siding

I'm trying to run a vent out from a basement bathroom shower. It's almost exactly in the middle of the lower floor. I can run relatively unobstructed through the space between the joists out to either the west or east wall, but each one appears to end in a joist (rim joist?) rather than just siding. Can I drill the vent through the rim joist, or do I need to find another route out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rim joists are over the foundation so you should be fine. That's how mine are done for bathroom vents, outside water faucets, etc.

Comment: I agree, it is standard to drill through for vents.